# Intersection of two normal subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let G be a group, and let A,B be normal subgroups of G. If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, does this mean that $ab \in A \cap B$?

Comment: @Libertron the question is in no way unclear. The answer is no, and I have no idea what you are trying to prove in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ has more than one element, then this is never true.  $A = G$ and $B = \{1_G\}$ are normal subgroups of $G$.  Let $a \in A$ be any element which is not the identity, and let $b = 1_G \in B$.  Then $ab = a$ does not lie in $A \cap B = \{1_G\}$.

Maybe you are thinking of the analogue of normal subgroups in ring theory, that is ideals.  If $I, J$ are ideals of a (commutative) ring $R$, and $a \in I, b \in J$, then certainly $ab \in I \cap J$.

Comment: If $R$ is noncommutative you need $I$ to be a right ideal and $J$ to be a left ideal respectively.